# Convert command line cURL to PHP cURL (with authentication)

Tags: php, curl, post

I want to convert command line cURL to PHP cURL in order to have better control.

Note it is included authentication with MYUSER and MYTOKEN.

Linux server is running Apache 2 and PHP 7.2.

```
curl -u 'MYUSER:MYTOKEN' 'https://example.com' -X POST --data '{"domainNames":["example.org","site2.com"]}'
```

What PHP code would you use to obtain the same functionality?

Comment: (Of course, one could find better duplicates with a bit more search effort.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used PHP cURL, but I have done stuff using PHP exec. WARNING this is not completely recommended. But here is what I think you can be able to do:

```
<?php
   echo exec('curl -u \'MYUSER:MYTOKEN\' \'https://example.com\' -X POST --data \'{"domainNames":["example.org","site2.com"]}\'');
?>
```

More advanced examples can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Along with this which is what you might actually be looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: (If you use double quotes for the encapsulation you don't need to escape the single quotes)

Comment: @user3783243 I tried that but `{"domainNames":["example.org","site2.com"]}` has double quotes then I would have to escape that right?

Comment: Yes, or looks like that is JSON so maybe, put it into an array and do `json_encode`.